# Unable to determine where CSS margins/padding are coming from

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

http://dev.bikeframeofmind.org/

Would someone mind taking a look at that page? I am attempting to get the center of the page to be white up to the nav bar, the bottom of the page, and horizontally to the shadow on both sides.

I am unsure where this padding is coming from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's coming from the `body`'s `.container` class.  You'll also need to set the navbar's `margin-bottom` to `0`.